# How to make multiple words rotate for a place in a sentence

Tags: jquery, css, html

I couldn't find any tutorial on this - nor could I find an example to give you (even though I have seen this done before), and I can't work out how to code this.

I want to have a sentence, say:

> Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum **faucibus** dolor auctor.

and I would like the bold **faucibus** to rotate with **Fringilla**, **Vulputate** and **Ligula** every three seconds - kind of like a slideshow.

So just to clarify, the sentence after three seconds would look like this:

> Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum **Fringilla** dolor auctor.

I'm not extremely experienced with coding so any help, or link to a tutorial site or anything would be appreciated a lot!

Comment: I created a lightweight zero dependency library for this exact thing https://github.com/slixites/cycleable ... If you're interested, I posted a blog about this https://www.slixites.com/blog/inline-text-cycling-with-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with javascript, I'd recommend using the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library for this. The simplest way to do it is to place the word you wish to change in a span in your HTML file:

```
Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum <span id="rotate_word">faucibus</span> dolor auctor.
```

After this, go to your javascript (with jQuery loaded) and try the following:

```
// Define initial variables.
var words = ["Fringilla", "Vulputate", "Ligula", "faucibus"];
var count = 0;

/*
 * The reason we do the following twice is because setInterval won't
 * initially call the changeWord function until 3 seconds has passed,
 * by doing it once first we make sure that we are changing the word
 * as soon as it starts.
 */

changeWord(); // Call the changeWord function
setInterval(changeWord, 3000); // Call it every 3 seconds

function changeWord() {

    // Define the word to create
    var current_word = words[count];
    console.log(current_word);

    // Change the word in the HTML
    $("#rotate_word").html(current_word);

    // Get the next word index in the array
    count++;

    // If we've reached the end of the word list, go back to the start
    if (count == words.length) { count = 0; }
}
```

I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltxh9/11/) to show a working demonstration.

Comment: You're welcome! Amazed someone stumbled on this question, it was from so long ago.

Answer (score 0):

Found something!

[Here's the link to the codrops article](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/17/rotating-words-with-css-animations/)

And here's the codrops provided (incase the link changes):

**All code provided is the work of Mary Lou, not my own**

```
<section class="rw-wrapper">
<h2 class="rw-sentence">
    <span>Real poetry is like</span>
    <span>creating</span>
    <div class="rw-words rw-words-1">
        <span>breathtaking moments</span>
        <span>lovely sounds</span>
        <span>incredible magic</span>
        <span>unseen experiences</span>
        <span>happy feelings</span>
        <span>beautiful butterflies</span>
    </div>
    <br />
    <span>with a silent touch of</span>
    <div class="rw-words rw-words-2">
        <span>sugar</span>
        <span>spice</span>
        <span>colors</span>
        <span>happiness</span>
        <span>wonder</span>
        <span>happiness</span>
    </div>
</h2>
</section>
```

And the CSS:

```
.rw-wrapper{
width: 80%;
position: relative;
margin: 110px auto 0 auto;
font-family: 'Bree Serif';
padding: 10px;
}

.rw-sentence{
margin: 0;
text-align: left;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

.rw-sentence span{
color: #444;
white-space: nowrap;
font-size: 200%;
font-weight: normal;
}

.rw-words{
display: inline;
text-indent: 10px;
}

.rw-words span{
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
color: #6b969d;
}

.rw-words-1 span{
animation: rotateWordsFirst 18s linear infinite 0s;
}
.rw-words-2 span{
animation: rotateWordsSecond 18s linear infinite 0s;
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(2) { 
animation-delay: 3s; 
color: #6b889d;
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(3) { 
animation-delay: 6s; 
color: #6b739d; 
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(4) { 
animation-delay: 9s; 
color: #7a6b9d;
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(5) { 
animation-delay: 12s; 
color: #8d6b9d;
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(6) {  
animation-delay: 15s; 
color: #9b6b9d;
}

@keyframes rotateWordsFirst {
0% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-in; height: 0px; }
8% { opacity: 1; height: 60px; }
19% { opacity: 1; height: 60px; }
25% { opacity: 0; height: 60px; }
100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes rotateWordsSecond {
0% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-in; width: 0px; }
10% { opacity: 0.3; width: 0px; }
20% { opacity: 1; width: 100%; }
27% { opacity: 0; width: 100%; }
100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

Comment: This isn't as flexible as a JS solution because you'd need to write new CSS rules every time you add a new child element.

Answer (score 0):

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W3DV4/9/), let me know if that works for you.

```
var words = ['Fringilla', 'Vulputate', 'Ligula', 'faucibus'];
var current = 0;
var element = $('#target');
setInterval(function () {
    current = (current==words.length) ? 0 : current;
    element.html(words[current]);
    current += 1;
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are after this stuff:

```
var list = ['Fringilla', 'Vulputate', 'Ligula', 'faucibus'];
var o = 0;

setInterval(function () {
    var w = list[o];
    $('p').each(function () {
        $(this).find('strong').fadeOut('fast', function () {
            $(this).html(w).fadeIn();
        });
    });
    (o == list.length) ? 0 : o++;
}, 3000);
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S5wwf/)